# I do I write this in .LESS?

Tags: less

I have a css output and I want to write this code in .LESS I see it uses the ">" to target down.

how do you write that in less to target with ">"

```
.clever-menu ul.clever-mega-menu > li.level0.active > a span
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the equivalent in LESS

```
.clever-menu {
  ul.clever-mega-menu {
    > li.level0.active {
      > a span {
        color: black;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be .clever-menu {}